# Use Neural Network to predict outcome on strings being the conditions

Tags: string, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm currently working on a project where I need to use some sort of neural network to predict something on premise of string data, the problem is that string data is not something a neural network can deal with, so I have researched the ways of indexing Strings into numeric values. The problem is that most methods use words and word lists, like the word bag concept, but this does not apply to my problem, because I'm dealing with log data consisting of things with symbols, letters and numbers all in one without words or something similar.

Is there an algorithm that can handle numbers well or is there some kind of way of efficiently representing strings in numeric form?

Comment: Can't you just normalize each letter's code to be within [0;1] range and then feed each letter to a corresponding input neuron? For example, for a 8-bit ASCII text you would divide each letter's code by 255, so letter `A` (octal code 101) will become `101 / 255 = 0.3960784313`. Each number will have a unique number and it's very easy to implement. I'm not an expert on neural networks, so I don't know if there are any caveats with this approach.

Comment: Need more info about your situation. What kind of network are you using (e.g. is it recurrent)? How do you need to process the inputs (e.g. character-by character, word-by-word, or set-of-multiple-words)? Here I mean words to be generalized blocks of symbols, not necessarily English words. Does your log contain repeatable words? Can you post some example log data?

Comment: [One-Hot-Coding](https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science) + [LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

Comment: with one hot encoding, what if a never before seen word comes up in future log files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by programming a word to vector feature extraction program. This type of program translates words into a multi dimensional vector system depending on criterions such as common words that come before it, number of letters and frequency of occurance. This allowed the numeric representation of the words to keep meaning and context and allowed the program to handle words that it has never seen before. There are many open source Word2Vec programs available and if you just google the name anyone can find sufficient resources to create one themselves if they have a similar problem to mine.